# Using regex in ls and mv

Tags: shell, ls, rename, wildcards

I have a directory structure like this

```
├── UK
│   ├── BuyBand_go_UK.png
│   ├── BuyBand_go_UK.svg
│   ├── BuyBand_K.png
│   ├── BuyBand_K.svg
│   ├── BuyBago_UK.png
│   ├── BuyBago_UK.svg
│   ├── BuyBand_ch_Logo_UK.png
│   └── BuyBand_ch_Logo_UK.svg
└── US
    ├── BuyBand_go_US.png
    ├── BuyBand_go_US.svg
    ├── BuyBand_S.png
    ├── BuyBand_S.svg
    ├── BuyBago_UK.png
    ├── BuyBago_UK.svg
    ├── BuyBand_ch_Logo_US.png
    └── BuyBand_ch_Logo_US.svg
```

How can I move all files in both `UK` and `US` directory in parent directory in one command?

This is what I've tried:

```
   mv (US|UK)/* .
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this from the parent directory:

```
mv {UK,US}/* .
```

The `{A,B,...}` syntax is similar to the `(A|B|...)` syntax used in regular expressions.

If you have dotfiles (hidden files) in those directories that aren't showing up in your listing, run

```
mv {UK,US}/{*,.*} .
```

The `*` glob will expand to all files and directories except for those starting with dots. The `.*` glob will expand to all of the dotfiles.

Comment: Note that `{a,b}` is not POSIX. For a completely portable solution, `mv UK/* US/* .` or in this very specific case `mv U[KS]/* .` instead.